# lining up multiple dd tags

Tags: css, layout

I have a dl where the dt's may have multiple dd's that I want to line up.  Unfortunately, the second dl line shifts left. How can I adjust the styling to prevent this?  I cannot edit the html since I get it from an app, and this is only an example, there are anywhere from 6 to 10 dt tags per page that have more than one dd so this has to be a general purpose solution.

```css
dl {
    width: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ff0;
}
dt {
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    background: #cc0;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
}
dd {
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    background: #dd0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>Test McTesterson</h3>
  <dl>
    <dt>Personal Phone</dt> 
    <dd>555-555-5555</dd>
    <dt>Personal Email</dt> 
    <dd>test@test.com</dd>
    <dt>Address</dt> 
    <dd>
      <span>123 Main St</span>
    </dd>
    <dd> 
      <span>Cityburg</span> 
      <span>Qa</span> 
      <span>12345</span>
    </dd>
    <dt>Birthdate</dt> 
    <dd>19801230</dd>
  </dl>
<body>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, was this problem solved to your satisfaction? Or were there outstanding problems with the posted solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
dd + dd {
    display: block; /* to force new line */
    margin: 0 0 0 4em; /* whatever the width of dt */
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best bet assuming IE6 won't need to be supported (as it should be).

Answer (score 0):

You could also not use multiple `dd`'s and just put all the info into a single `dd`.

Comment: except I get dd's from the app, and I really don't want to ahve to write something that changes their tags because they contain class attributes some javascript relies on that is not shown here.